# TOC, lof, lot, centering Formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am trying to format my table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables. I need to center the titles of all but when I do this extra spacing is added to the list of figures and list of tables within the table of contents.

Here is my code (I removed parts that were unnecessary):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{dissertation}
[2015/06/05 v0.2 Dissertation Class]
\newif\if@endorse

\DeclareOption{endorse}{\@endorsetrue}
\DeclareOption{noendorse}{\@endorsefalse}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ExecuteOptions{noendorse, 12pt, letterpaper}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{report}
\RequirePackage[hmargin={1.5in,1in},vmargin=1in,foot=0.5in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\RequirePackage{needspace}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}

\newcommand\makefrontmatter{%
  \maketitle 
  \pdfbookmark[chapter]{\contentsname}{toc}
  \tableofcontents \newpage \listoftables \newpage \listoffigures
  \clearpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic} \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax \global\let\abstract\relax
  \global\let\dedication\relax}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill \normalfont Table of Contents \hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalsize \normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalsize \normalfont}

\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\normalsize \normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\normalsize \normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\normalsize \normalfont}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\hfill \normalfont List of Figures \hfill}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hfill \normalfont List of tables \hfill}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\normalfont}
```

Here is what I am getting:

[image: TOC]

[image: lof]

Comment: How about adding some other, necessary parts so we can create a minimal document that we can work with? See [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
% tocloftcenteringprob.tex  SE 573019
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%%% center ToC, etc titles
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\Large\bfseries} \renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries} \renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}
\centering
A FIGURE
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]